# How do I remove words from multilingual text?

Tags: regex, algorithm, unicode, utf-8

I have two versions of the same document (D, say) containing multilingual text (English and others):

I. One is encoded in ASCII with Unicode code-points represented as character entity references (i.e. Unicode characters are of the form &#N, where N is the decimal equivalent of the Unicode hex value)

II. The other is UTF-8 encoding.

Q 1:

I have a separate list of words (encoded in UTF-8, and in more than one language), that I have to remove from the document D. How should I proceed?

Can I use regex to clean D? For doc type I, I believe I have to specify the whole &#N patterns for each word in the list when I form the regex.

Should the task be easier for doc type II, now that I can specify the non-English characters directly in the regex (my emacs is configured to use these non-English fonts) ?

Q 2:

I have a huge collections of such document D's. What should be the best algorithm to remove words from each of these documents? A table look-up is straight-forward but probably the slowest. Should I regex through each?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a list of possible languages. As described, your requirements are difficult if not impossible to fulfill for every language.

Comment: The text is in English and Bengali.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest processing the entities first so that the two sorts of files look the same. When you’re done removing, put the first set back into their encoded form.